# Material-UI datepicker - add more info to a day

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

im using Material-UI datepicker on React.

it is possible to add more info to day component, **without** rendring my own day component ?

[something like in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55pAA.png)

thanks.